# p-th powers in p-adic field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Denote by $K$ the completion of $\bigcup_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{Q}_p (\zeta_{p^n})$, where $\zeta_{p^n}$ is a $p^n$-th root of unity. Is it true that any element in $K$ is a $p$-th power of some element in $K$?

I am grateful for any help!

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Servaes: Well, first it suffices to prove that every $x \in K$ of absolute value $1$ has a $p$-th root. Now the obvious idea would be Hensel's Lifting Lemma, but the derivative has the factor $p$, which is the main problem.

Comment: @Servaes: Write $f(x) = x^p-u$ for some $u \in K$ with $|u|=1$. If $f(\alpha) = 0$, then this means that $|\alpha|=1$ as well. But then $|f'(\alpha)|=|p|=p^{-1}$, so we need to construct $\alpha \in K$ such that $|\alpha|=1$ and $|f(\alpha)|<|f'(\alpha)|^2 = p^{-2}$. But why does such an $\alpha$ exist for any given $u$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not true, except conceivably for $p=2$.

Your extension is (the completion of) an abelian field over $\Bbb Q_p$, but even in the case $p=3$, $\sqrt[3]3$ isn’t in it, ’cause $\Bbb Q_3(\zeta_3,\sqrt[3]3\,)$ is nonabelian over $\Bbb Q_3$.

Now that I have your attention, I would like to encourage you to become friends with the stronger version of Hensel, which is not about finding roots, but about lifting a factorization over the residue field to a factorization over the original complete field. I’m away from home right now, so I can’t give a precise reference, but it’s in the excellent book of Gouvêa.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am aware that there exists a factorization-version of HLL, but it has the disadvantage that it does not generalize (to my knowledge) to multivariate polynomials.

Comment: Maybe not. But the stronger version does all sorts of things that the weak does not, and it’s really useful.